# Why is my $request->user() null when I am making Oauth2 requests with passport Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

My user on request is for some reason null.

```
public function handle($request, $next, ...$scopes)
{
    dd($request->user());
}
```

I recieve
[null even though I have all the credentials there and valid][1]
[My kernel.php][2]

[My guards in auth.php][3]

[My middleware now updated][4]

So moving from my previous problem now I am getting

{    "message": "Unauthenticated." }
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/efdax.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1lUI.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TulwQ.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1AEE.png

Comment: do you have the `auth` middleware applied to the route you are trying to reach? what is your default guard? what is this middleware and how is it applied to the route?

Comment: Route::middleware(['auth','scopes:view-products'])->group(function () {}
Route::middleware(['auth:api','scopes:view-products'])->group(function () {}
I didnt have the auth there you were right I tried both options I sent rn and my request are not going trough now at all

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Please never share code hidden in screenshots. Usually, code is shared best in text form. Also, share yuor attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I noticed from [your latest comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73298099/why-is-my-request-user-null-when-i-am-making-oauth2-requests-with-passport-l#comment129452471_73298099), did you mean singular `scope:view-products` and not plural `scopes`?

Also, I've shared below laravel 9.x documentation link.

And I'd suggest retracing your steps, from Step 1 to current of setting up Laravel Passport. I reckon one or two steps are missed - like the guard setup, or scope setup. Or best guess about typo mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#check-for-any-scopes

Edit: Issuer have discovered and resolved scoping issue, [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73305186/5323274). Well done!

Comment: I think scopes/scope doesnt have any role here since both of them are actual functionalities both if you use only 1 scope would have same result + I did setup guard and also scopes its just not mentioned here I will add it by editing question :)

Comment: Yes I believe you're right, that scope / scopes should not be an issue. Based on your updated question (now with 3rd parameter, `...$scopes`), I'm afraid I haven't actioned a setup like that before, as it looks like it's in the middleware itself? Also to add, if you have `sentry` integration or checking the `laravel.log` file may provide more clues, to your Error 500.

Answer (score 1):

My bad everything works I was supposed to use different tipe of scoping https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens
Example:

```
Route::middleware(['client:view-products', 'client.auth'])->group(function () {}
```